# how to write a method to reverse a 2D array

Tags: java

I got this question to solve

> Write a method that takes a two-dimensional array of type integer as a parameter and return
> the inverse of the array (the rows become the columns and vice versa).

that is what I did through searching, but it shows a bunch of errors

```
public static class inverse{

    public static int[][] arrayInverse(int[][] A){
        int[][] B = new int[3][3];
        for(int i=0; i<B.length/2;i++){
            for (int j=0; j<B[i].length/2;j++) {
                int swap = B[i][j];
                B[B.length - i - 1] = swap;
            }
        }
        return swap;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What errors does it raise?

Comment: It looks like you're doing the wrong thing. The question does not say *reverse* the array. It says swap the rows and the columns.

Comment: My best advise is to read about matrix transpose, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-transpose-of-a-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace between columns and rows

```
public class inverse {
    /**
     * The entry point of application.
     *
     * @param args the input arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ints[][] = {{1, 2, 3},
                {5, 6, 7},
                {9, 10, 11},
                {12, 13, 14}
        };
        print2D(ints);
        System.out.println("\n");
        print2D(arrayInverse(ints));
    }

    /**
     * Array inverse int [ ] [ ].
     *
     * @param A the a
     * @return the int [ ] [ ]
     */
    public static int[][] arrayInverse(int[][] A) {
        if (A.length == 0 || A[0].length == 0) {
            System.out.println("A.length==0 || A[0].length==0");
            return A;
        }
        int[][] B = new int[A[0].length][A.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < B[i].length; j++) {
                B[i][j] = A[j][i];
            }
        }
        return B;
    }

    /**
     * Print 2 d.
     *
     * @param mat the mat
     */
    public static void print2D(int mat[][]) {
        // Loop through all rows
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

1 2 3
5 6 7
9 10 11
12 13 14

1 5 9 12
2 6 10 13
3 7 11 14

Comment: And what about a 4x4 array? Or an array where the number of rows and columns are different?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Answer updated and different length supported.

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned in the comments, the task is to [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the input array *the rows become the columns and vice versa*

If the input 2D array is square (the number of the rows is the same as the number of columns), the most efficient way would be to swap the elements below and over the main diagonal: `a[i][j] ⇄ a[j][i]` without using extra array:

```java
public static int[][] transposeSquare(int[][] arr) {
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
        // select the elements only above the main diagonal
        for (int j = i + 1, m = arr[i].length; j < m; j++) {
            int tmp = arr[i][j];
            arr[i][j] = arr[j][i];
            arr[j][i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

However, in general case of a rectangular matrix it may be needed to create a new array/matrix of size `M x N` instead of `N x M`, and copy the values from the input in appropriate order (no swap is needed then):

```java
public static int[][] transpose(int[][] arr) {
    int[][] result = new int[arr[0].length][arr.length];
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, m = arr[i].length; j < m; j++) {
            result[j][i] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `transposeSquare` returns the input as is. You seem to transpose twice.

Comment: @saka1029, right, the code has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution.  It will transpose any matrix, including a ragged one.

```
List<int[][]> demo = List.of(
        new int[][] { { 1 }, { 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } },
        new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } },
        new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } });

for (int[][] arr : demo) {
    System.out.println("Original");
    for (int[] b : arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
    System.out.println("Transposed");
    for (int[] b : transpose(arr)) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
Original
[1]
[2, 3, 4]
[5, 6]
Transposed
[1, 2, 5]
[3, 6]
[4]

Original
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
Transposed
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]

Original
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Transposed
[1, 6]
[2, 7]
[3, 8]
[4, 9]
[5, 10]
```

- first, find the resulting number of rows, which is the maximum number of columns in the source matrix.
- Then simply iterate thru the matrix, creating the new rows and copying the appropriate values of each column to their new row. Since the rows may be of different lengths, a check is made to ensure the value exists in the current row.
- then copy that row of the proper length to the transposed row.

```
public static int[][] transpose(int[][] nums) {
    int maxRows = nums[0].length;
    for (int[] ar : nums) {
        maxRows = Math.max(maxRows, ar.length);
    }
    int[][] trans = new int[maxRows][];
    for (int r = 0; r < maxRows; r++) {
        int[] row = new int[nums.length];
        int cc = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < row.length; c++) {
            if (r < nums[c].length) {
                row[cc++] = nums[c][r];
            }
        }
        trans[r] = Arrays.copyOf(row, cc);
    }
    return trans;
}
```

prints